# making a link to take you from inbox to app page in correct app store (Mobile)

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-play, app-store

(this is for mobile devices)

For marketing purposes, I need to send an email to a potential user with a generic link. once the link is clicked it will take the user to the app store of the user's device (ios app store or Google Play) showing my app so they can install it.

How can I implement a link like this?
p.s. my app has a server side plus a client side.

Comment: writing code would be a good start...

Comment: @MarcB Like JavaScript code? I do not have a vision for how to solve this but would a page be able to redirect me to the correct store? thanks

Comment: There are services like https://www.geni.us/features out there that recognise the devices and redirect them to the right store. Obviously I would not recommend to invent the wheel again ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Oddie, I didn't realize this feature is so big that it takes a third party help.